# How to setup dynamic list for a slot?

Tags: amazon-lex

I building a bot in amazon lex , I have a usecase where , I will give the user option to choose flower to order , My list of flowers is dynamic and will be got from a service , how should I build a slot for this use case ?

Answer (score -1):

For a very similar question can go here: [Custom Slot Type with AWS Lambda hook for Amazon Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842310/custom-slot-type-with-aws-lambda-hook-for-amazon-lex)

AWS exposes an API to dynamically create slot types, and updating the LEX bot. (see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_PutSlotType.html, and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_CreateSlotTypeVersion.html)

Your best bet is to use their LEX API to update the custom slot type whenever you detect a change in your list. There seems to be no "native" way to specify a dynamics list.